# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 129

Tags: c#, indexing, formatting

I'm new to C# & I believe it is a syntax error or a connection error

Here is the code that it highlights as the error.

```
   private void btnLoadExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       String PathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel    8,0;HDR=yes;    \";";
       OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathConn);

       OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdaptor = new OleDbDataAdapter("select 8 form [" + TBSheet.Text + "$]", conn);
       DataTable dt = new DataTable();

       myDataAdaptor.Fill(dt);

       dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
   }
```

Comment: Should `select 8 form` not be `select * from` ?

Comment: Yes it should it has been changed but the same problem accurres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you debug the code and have a look at the character at position 129 - the error will be there.

That said, it does look like you're mixing a single quote and double quote in your "Extended Properties" part - try something like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=yes\";";
```

(I've also changed "8,0" to "8.0", as indicated on [connectionstrings.com](https://connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/), though it might be that either works)